# Community Login Page - Can you hide the Standard?

Tags: community, login

For a Customer Community we are using a custom Login Page, and if someone was smart and went to the /login page that Salesforce has as standard they could see and use that login which we don't want.  Is there anything we can do to hide/disable that or have it redirect to the page we are using?

[image]

Comment: can set your current page as login page.

Comment: It is setup like that in community admin, see my update with image.

Answer (score 2):

So I needed to use Site URL Redirects to accomplish this.  By setting it to redirect when someone attempts to access that page.

[image]

Comment: This works unless there is a parameter on the source URL, like /login?abc=123.  Then the redirect fails and you land on the standard login page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this check box with certain page types to hide the Employee Login Link

[image]